# How can I forward my localhost to my public IP on a VPS?

Tags: linux, web, localhost, vps

I'm running a website on my Linux VPS.

This is what I get on my terminal when the website is running:

```
Navigate to https://127.0.0.1:7443 in a browser
```

The problem is that I cannot connect to this on the browser because it's not MY machine's localhost.

Is there a way I can forward this to my VPS's Public IP?

for example, the IP address I use to access the server? To explain better I want to access the website from anywhere from my phone, laptop, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use iptables/firewalld such as port recirection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably searching for is one of these tools:

- https://ngrok.com/
- http://localtunnel.github.io/www/

These tools will let you access your local page from anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 0):

It should be just: `<your VPS IP>:7443`

make sure you have an elastic IP (public IP) tied to your VPS instance